# Bad character escape sequence

Tags: reactjs, graphql, graphql-js

I getting an error after running yarn dev in windows:

`./api/graphql/_generated/resolvers.js
SyntaxError: D:\gondor\api\graphql_generated\resolve
rs.js: Bad character escape sequence (1:378)`

Could not understand what is the problem. Can anybody please explain me the solution.

this is the project: https://github.com/coding-blocks/gondor

Comment: Please edit your question to include the relevant code.

Comment: @DanielRearden What else code should I provide?

Comment: The code that the error is pointing to. It would also be helpful to know what commands "yarn dev" is actually running.

Comment: @DanielRearden this is the project: https://github.com/coding-blocks/gondor